# Submitting Linux kernel code

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

As a semester project I have modified a file of Linux kernel source code (related to memory management), to improve the existing structure. It includes addition of some new functions.

But I couldn't compile it successfully as I don't have enough knowledge of writing source code (no problem in the written code, I have tested the prototype on C compiler, just to verify).

Now I just want to submit my idea to Linux community. I have the required code with me, it is just required to be integrated with the source code. [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org) has nice guide to submit the patch. But since I haven't compiled it successfully, I can't submit as a patch.

Is there any way to submit my project idea to Linux Community, so that they can integrate it to the source code?

Comment: The OS that you are using is Gnu/Linux + X11 + …. there is much more to it then the kernel. Also the kernel is one of the hardest parts to program. It may be better to start on another part. Maybe even another language (C is hard).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in your situation, I doubt that you’d get much traction by submitting non-compiling code in the hope that “the community” will integrate it. What is likely to work better, is if you join one of the various communities which exist to help developers new to kernel development learn the ropes. One such community is [the kernel newbies mailing list](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/mailman/listinfo/kernelnewbies); take a look at the archives to get a feel for the discussions that happen there, then subscribe and join in the conversation.